# Why are my gems not found when I do 'bundle install'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When I add a gem to my gemfile like so:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'meta_search', '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.4'
```

and go to my terminal and type:

```
bundle install
```

I get this:

```
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using atomic (1.1.10)
Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.0)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
Using activemodel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.0)
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.0)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.4.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.10.0)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
Using rails (4.0.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using sass (3.2.9)
Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)
Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
Using uglifier (2.1.2)
```

The gems listed are okay here and that was from the initial install of this app, but adding new gems to the gemfile will not let them get installed, so when I run a command that is explicit to that gem, I get errors like so:

```
rails generate active_admin:install
Could not find generator active_admin:install
```

I am not sure if this is an issue with my gemfile.

Comment: have checked with bundle update?

Comment: What are your contents of .bundle/config ?

Comment: 1. Be sure that the changes in the `Gemfile` were saved. 
 2. Try it on a fresh rvm gemset

Comment: check are you at the root of the application, or editing the same gemfile where currently you are at terminal?

Comment: Where is .bundle/config ?

Comment: At the root of your project, there should be a `.bundle` directory. It may be empty, in which case that doesn't help

Comment: deleted and installed all again with rails -v 4 put in the new gems in the gemfile but when I run bundle update I get Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails generate active_admin:install`?

Comment: why bundle not rails?

Comment: Use `bundle exec` to only use the gems in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the end.

The rails 4 version does not like the current version of active_admin so I had to use the edge method of getting my gemfile working for these gems to install. Which as as follows for anyone who wants to know:

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc2'

gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'ransack',             github: 'ernie/ransack',         branch: 'rails-4'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'formtastic',         github: 'justinfrench/formtastic', branch: 'rails4beta'
```

The reason it never worked in the first place was a conflict in my gemfile with a version of rails, so I restarted my machine and started again and it worked.